# Why are we using combination in this problem instead of permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> What is the number of non-negative integers of at most $4$ digits whose digits are increasing?

- The answer to this problem is $10\choose 4$.
- But, I want to know why are we using combination instead of permutation when the order matters in this question?

Comment: Once you've chosen the digits, there is only one possible order - the ascending one.

Comment: In fact the order does *not* matter. We just have to pick 4 digits out of 10. Then we are ready because we do not have to puzzle *how* to order them. That is clear on forehand.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: We say to use permutations "when the order matters," but what we really mean is "when each different sequence of the same objects is a different result."

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\binom {10}{4}=210$ is only correct if we count leading $0$s as distinct digits, and so allow $123 \equiv 0123$, but disallow $12 \equiv 0012$.

If any number of leading $0$s are allowed (in which case the phrase "non-negative integers" also allows $0$ itself) then the answer is $\binom 9 4 + \binom 9 3 + \binom 9 2 + \binom 9 1 + \binom 9 0 = 256$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.